# Left joining on one of multiple columns from right table, depending on value from the left table

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables which I need to join: **Table A**, which has to be the leftmost table, and **Table B**, which must be joined onto it via LEFT JOIN. I cannot use a UNION in this scenario.

Table A:

| ID | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | blahblahblah |
| 2 | yadayadayada |
| 3 | whatever |

Table B:

| Primary_ID | Secondary_ID | More_Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | etc etc |
| 4 | 3 | doesn't matter |

The ideal way for the join to work is to join on the primary ID first, and if there is no match, then to join on the secondary ID.

Joined Results:

| A.ID | A.Data | B.Primary_ID | B.Secondary_ID | B.More_Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blahblahblah | 1 | 3 | etc etc |
| 2 | yadayadayada |  |  |  |
| 3 | whatever | 4 | 3 | doesn't matter |

An OR clause could do the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.Primary_ID OR A.ID = B.Secondary_ID
```

however it is very inefficient on a larger scale.

Another option is to break it out into two joins and coalesce the results:

```
SELECT A.*, 
       COALESCE(B1.Primary_ID, B2.Primary_ID),
       COALESCE(B1.Secondary_ID, B2.Secondary_ID),
       COALESCE(B1.More_Data, B2.More_Data), 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B1 ON A.ID = B.Primary_ID
LEFT JOIN B2 ON A.ID = B2.Secondary_ID
```

But this is not sustainable on the scale I am working with.

So, is there any way of achieving the results without a UNION, or an OR clause in the join statement, or by breaking it out into multiple joins?

Comment: I am puzzled why you are not open to using an UNION ALL to split the 4 branches of the LEFT JOIN

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim would love to, but the BI tool I am working with (Looker) does not handle unions well. At the level I am working with it would be easier to start the schema from scratch than to try to introduce a union at the data modeling level

Comment: Which dbms are you actually using? Remove the unrelated dbms tags.

Comment: Your queries and the desired output are **inconsistent**. The queries return the `A.id = 3` *twice*, both rows joined on the `Secondary_ID = 3`. My answer produce your expected result. Pls, clarify!

Comment: "But this is not sustainable on the scale I am working with"  Why isn't it?  How can we help solve the problem if you don't tell us what it is?

Comment: @hov if you can do a sub-select you can use UNION ALL inside that sub-select, unless you are saying Lookers snippets cannot parse/handle the UNION ALL and thus do not allow this, at which point putting this into a VIEW would make sense.

Comment: to add to @MarmiteBomber 's point, `whatever` matches both table b rows on the 3 with your stated logic. or match of first or second. So your ideal results are not in fact what you get from your suggest OR SQL. Please update the question.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your concern with the join with `OR` in predicate as this could lead to an inneficient join.

But I do not understand why the two join option with *coalesce* is *not sustainable* - I would follow this approach.

Anyway if you are on the search for further variations bellow is one example - checking first which key (primary / secondary) should be used and performing than simple outer join on single `id`

```
with one_id_tb as (
select 
 coalesce(ta.id,ta2.id) id,
 Primary_ID, Secondary_ID,
 More_Data
from tb
left outer join ta on tb.Primary_ID = ta.id
left outer join ta ta2 on tb.Secondary_ID = ta2.id
)
select 
  ta.id a_id, ta.data a_data, Primary_ID, Secondary_ID,More_Data
from ta 
left outer join one_id_tb
on ta.id = one_id_tb.id

a_id|a_data      |primary_id|secondary_id|more_data     |
----+------------+----------+------------+--------------+
   1|blahblahblah|         1|           3|etc etc       |
   2|yadayadayada|          |            |              |
   3|whatever    |         4|           3|doesn't matter|
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT
A.ID,
A.Data,
B.Primary_ID,
B.Secondary_ID,
B.More_Data
FROM
TableA A
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT Primary_ID, Secondary_ID, More_Data
FROM TableB
UNION
SELECT Primary_ID, Secondary_ID, More_Data
FROM TableB
) B ON A.ID = B.Primary_ID OR A.ID = B.Secondary_ID;
```

Comment: What exactly do you think this is achieving? And how does this "not use UNION" like the OP asked?